# Help with character turning?

Tags: unity

I'm simply trying to make my character turn in his place, whether he's standing still or moving, currently, he isn't turning what-so-ever. Here is the code that I currently have for turning:

### I AM NO LONGER USING THIS TURNING FUNTION vvv

```
void Turning()
{
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit floorHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
    {
        Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
        playerToMouse.y = 0f;

        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
        playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
    }
}
```

So what should be happening is my character should turn and face toward wherever my mouse is pointing, but that isn't happening and I'm not sure why.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

---

### WHAT I AM USING NOW

I have alternatively tried another bit of code which I will post below, I completely got rid of what is above in place of this:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
transform.LookAt(mousePos);
```

This will actually make the camera follow the mouse, but it goes crazy, the camera seems to spin in circles rapidly : here is actually a gif of what is happening. https://gyazo.com/952da6c28e644b7b0e6500a597b6804e/preview Could anyone help me figure how how to fix it?

Comment: You need to **set** the rotation, not **move** it

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure how to make that happen

Comment: @Bálint: check the documentation. MoveRotation does indeed set the rotation. The "Move" part just means it will travel *to* that new rotation correctly with regard to physics & Rigidbody interpolation settings. BondyeLwa: Your first code sample looks right. Have you verified that the raycast is finding a hit where you expect, and that the physics rotation isn't being overridden by another script or animation? As for your second code — is your camera parented to the player and turning with them? You'll likely want to put some dampening on the camera follow so the feedback loop doesn't run away.

Comment: @DMGregory right, sorry

Comment: Is the transform controlled by an Animator? Because if that's the case it's likely that your changes in Update are being overwritten by the animation, as Update is performed before the animation update https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: Your camera is going crazy because as the camera rotates, the point that the mouse is over changes, causing the camera to rotate again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to fix this problem but I do know what the problem is, on the back end. It is doing what you want it to do it is looking at the mouse, but as it moves so does the mouse so it is forever looking for that new rotation. It appears as its spinning because it is to the effect the world is moving the player is moving, the mouse is static but being static puts the mouse in a new location as its spinning so it's like a dog trying to catch its own tail. the world is spinning, the dog is spinning, the tail is static.

Comment: Hey, can you remove this because I answered the question with a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the mouse location to the center of the screen when the mouse moves. This is needed so that, like in @DaveBird 's answer, the camera does not chase its tail. you need to set the tail to nowhere until and after the mouse moves. So your second code is fine, you just need to set the mouse position to the center of the screen.